# Need assistance with locating an element on the page

Tags: selenium

How can i write an xpath that would give me the following element:`<span class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="sideData.orderRequestType == 'import'"> ORI - 643 </span>`?

Thank you!

Comment: you should ask your question much precise... But answering the question, this is example xpath: `//span[@class='ng-binding ng-scope']`

Comment: This is also correct xpath: `//span`, and this: `//*`. I dont know what is your problem :)

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the "span" part!

Comment: One more question, while you're here. I have this element `<select class="form-control input-sm input-required text-center ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-touched" ng-if="formData.order_request_status == STATUSES['OPEN'] && !oneCompany" ng-options="c.company_id as c.company_name for (id, c) in ownCompanies" data-ng-model="formData.company_id">`,

Comment: so i have written this line in order to find it `WebElement company = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@class='form-control input-sm input-required text-center ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-touched'][@data-ng-model='formData.company_id']")));`, but it gives me a Timeout Exception, waited for presence of the element. The xpath is working if i copy paste it into FireBug. Do you know what the problem could be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122919/discussion-between-kotoj-and-tudor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider what part of the element doesn't change. 
For example, if `class` parameter is always the same, you can build xpath based on `class`:

```
//span[@class='ng-binding ng-scope']
```